# Git - Best practice: How to switch very often between branches and avoid multiples commits?

Tags: git, branch

I am working on a validation software.
I keep on the master branch code that is always ready to launch tests.
So I develop the new features in other branches (dev for ex).
This is classic git workflow.

My concern is that it happens that I need to switch betwen master and dev 10 times a day because the designers ask me to check their updates.

At the moment I only know one way:

1. Commit my work on dev with message *"Regression required"*
2. Switch to master branch
3. Run regression and give feedbacks
4. Switch back on dev and keep on working

This is annoying because of the useless history created on dev branch.

Is there another **simple** way (I am a beginner) to avoid the multiple commits on dev branch?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: if you don't want to stash (which is the correct solution), or if you commit by accident, you have two options, either `git reset HEAD^` so the commit is not counted, and the changes are not lost, or after finishing work, `git commit --amend` so that you add up to that commit, without creating a new one, and you can change the commit message too.

Comment: At the beginning it was my idea. Try to updated the commit _Regression required_ when the next feature is ready on the dev branch. But I was sure there were a better way. Thanks for the commit tricks. I thought `--ammend` was _only_ for text! Now I know a little bit more powerfull...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before switching branches, do [`git stash`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-stash.html). This will record the current state of what you're working on in a way that is easy to recover. When you switch back to your dev branch, do `git stash pop`. This will re-apply those changes, and delete the stash so that it doesn't stay around in your history.

Comment: Thank you for those explanations. I going with the `stash` instead of the `clone` because for some reasons it is not so simple to duplicate the folders in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `git stash` is what you need.  There's help on it [here](http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It will be helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` your master repository, and run the regression tests from there.
Remember to run `git pull` to retrieve updates. And never commit to the cloned repository (or be prepared to merge that back to the master repository asap).

Comment: The `clone` seems to be a good way too. It is good to know this solution. Unfortunately, it is not easy for me to use this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several good suggestions here. My first thought is to have two clones, on on dev and one on master. Just change directories (similar to what ydroneaud is saying).

Another way, if you just want to run regression, is to use git archive to fetch a snapshot and test with that. Go to an empty directory and do:

```
git --git-dir=/my/dev/clone/.git archive master | tar xvf -
```

then build & test. Of course it makes sense to put this in a script.

Comment: Did I understand correctly if I say that this a way to clone the master branch without using the `clone` command?